# Picasa like apps for Mac

Tags: macos, software-rec, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best (cheap or free) image editing application for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/11111/best-cheap-or-free-image-editing-application-for-mac)

I have used iPhoto for years and decided to go with Picasa. After using it for a year, I am pretty annoyed with this app – I hate it –  and I would like to change to another one.

Which choices do I have beyond Picasa and iPhoto for Mac OS X?

Comment: So, apart from *hating* it: what did you not like, and what are your needs?

Comment: @Arjan: One is editing, the other is managing. You don't even see iPhoto or Picasa there.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me...

Comment: @Mr. Man - wasn't me but I thought about it.  I'd guess its because the question is so vague as to be nearly unanswerable.  He hate's Picasa but wants something like it?  Which parts does he like, which parts does he hate?  We don't even know what he was using it for. Without some details all we can do is list random programs that deal with images.

Comment: @Daniel, you may have a point about this not being a duplicate. (Though I wonder if there's no other duplicate then, *if* we would know what the requirements were.) -1 from me now too, for having been online without changing the question.

Comment: @bemace It's a rather easy question IMO; just ignore the whole first paragraph. Picasa and iPhoto are in the same general photo management application market, so this is what he wants. The question then might be vague, but there aren't really many possible answers that I know of. blueMarine, mentioned by birryree, is "only" cross-platform Java. I don't think there are any others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shoebox](http://www.kavasoft.com/Shoebox/), [Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/), [Aperture](http://www.apple.com/aperture/) and a combination of Finder/QuickLook/some image editing app.

All other options do a pretty decent job of hiding themselves on [iusethis](http://osx.iusethis.com) and [alternativeto](http://www.alternativeto.net).

Also, better problem description might be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean http://alternativeto.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Any particular features you want/desire that Picasa/iPhoto lacked or just weren't good at in the first place? Do you want free programs only, or are you open to commercial ware?

I use Apple Aperture and Adobe Lightroom, both of which are expensive (compared to Picasa/iPhoto) digital workflow tools mostly aimed at RAW photographers. Both are like iphoto on steroids.

For free alternatives there is BlueMarine.